# Nginx rewrite question

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Trying to convert over an apache config to nginx.

```
<Directory /usr/local/image/>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /key1 /usr/local/image
Alias /key2 /usr/local/image
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /usr/local/image/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))$ /handler.php
```

so a request to /key1/subdir1/subdir2/123.png OR /key2/subdir1/subdir2/123.png would look to /usr/local/image/subdir1/subdir2/123.png, serve it if it exists, or go to /handler.php if not (404)

I've tried:

```
    location ^~ /key1 {
     alias /usr/local/image/;
     error_page 404 /handler.php;
}
```

Which somewhat works - but I would like to limit this rule to only images (jp?g|gif|png) but the subdir1 & subdir2 values will vary.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently do this in nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~* /key[12]/(.*\.(jpe?g|gif|png)) {
    alias /usr/local/image/$1;
    error_page 404 /handler.php;
}
```

PS: I use `~*` for case insensitive matching.

---

**EDIT**

If your two aliases are completely different, you can put it into round brackets:

```
location ~* /(?:abc12345|12abcdef)/(.*\.(jpe?g|gif|png)) {
    alias /usr/local/image/$1;
    error_page 404 /handler.php;
}
```

- a question mask colon `?:` at the beginning of the group means not
  counting for back reference.

Comment: nice - if the two keys were significantly different (say /abc12345 & /12abcdef) would you split them into two different location statements?

Comment: You can put it into round brackets. Please check out my above edited answer.